# getting system account information java?

Tags: java, user-accounts

Is it possible to get the current account information (on computer) things like their username and profile picture using Java? any help would be appreciated

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html for a  a list of system properties available to the JVM on every OS.

You can then access a property using `String prop = System.getProperty("user.name")`.

There's no universal access to any profile picture that I know of. There might be OS-specific libraries for that.

Answer (score 3):

System account info is available through Java's system properties. For example:
System.getProperty("user.name") will return the username of the person who ran the java executable. Similarly, "user.home" will get that user's home directory. There are many properties, if you want the full list, check out System.getProperties().

However, when you say profile picture, it makes me wonder if you're talking about the user account for a web framework. If that's the case, I'm not sure how to help you, since I don't know what web framework you're using (and personally, I wouldn't be much help in any case, I'm not much of a web expert).

Comment: I know when I use XP and later Windows OSes, you can assign an image to your account, and that image appears on the screen where one chooses an account to log in with.  Maybe that's what he's after?